# React Native RadioForm initial not being updated

Tags: javascript, react-native

I set the initial value of my RadioForm with variable from my state. It initial has undefined value, then the value changes to 1, but it always show "Yes" in the page.

```
import RadioForm from 'react-native-simple-radio-button';

...

render() {
   const radio_props = [
      {label: 'Yes  ', value: 0 },
      {label: 'No', value: 1 }
   ];
   const test = this.state.myValue;
   console.log(test);

   ...

   <RadioForm
      radio_props={radio_props}
      initial={test}
      formHorizontal={true}
      labelHorizontal={true}
      buttonColor={'#2196f3'}
      animation={true}
      buttonSize={15}
      onPress={(text) => this.onChangeSettings(text, 'Test')}
  />
}
```

The console.log is showing:

```
undefined
undefined
1
```

Is the undefined generating the issue?

Answer (score 0):

While you can leave the initial state undefined. It is best to set the initial state to a value such as -1. Then do the following:

```
{this.state.test != -1 &&
   <RadioForm
      radio_props={radio_props}
      initial={test}
      formHorizontal={true}
      labelHorizontal={true}
      buttonColor={'#2196f3'}
      animation={true}
      buttonSize={15}
      onPress={(text) => this.onChangeSettings(text, 'Test')}
  />
}
```